# Random string generator c++

Tags: c++

I would like to generate list of strings with no repeats as follows

A1, A2 , A3 , A4 , B1 , B2 , B3 , B4 , C1, C2, C3, C4

this is the way I generate out my list of strings

```
std::string columns[] ={"A","B","C"};
std::string rows[]={"1","2","3","4"};
std::string columnsAndRows;

for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
        columnsAndRows=columns[i]+row[j];
        //possible to do something like this?
        columnAndRows.rand();
    }
}
```

but the problem is, I read about rand() and it returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and RAND_MAX. what should I do to generate a random string base on my desired requirements?

Comment: You can 'map' `rand()` results using the modulus function to your specific ranges.

Comment: `for(int j=0; j=10; j++)` Should be `for(int j=0; j==10; j++)`. The first one is assigning and not comparing.

Comment: I don't see what that code, or the example output you posted, has to do with randomness. Do you mean that you want to choose one of those two-character strings at random?

Comment: It also has the nasty side effect that the loop will not be looped.

Comment: You can simply construct the "list" `A1, A2, ...` and then [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) it. Be aware that `random_shuffle` uses `rand` by default, which is a) not very good (use C++11's PRNGs if possible) and b) requires seeding by `srand`.

Comment: @interjay I want to random strings,something like e.g(A1, A2) but rand() returns a returns a pseudo-random integral number. so I don't think rand() can random string like e.g(A1,A2) since A1 is not a integer number and I am not sure how it is done and I seeking help for it

Comment: @user2947249: are you aware, by the way, that your sample code does not generate random *strings* (plural) but only one and its value is immediately overwritten by the next iteration?

Comment: @user2947249 Surely you can see it's easy to turn an integer 1, 2, 3, or 4, into a letter A, B, C, or D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `std::rand` with the modulus [might not be a good idea](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). Instead you can easily construct a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of possible elements and do a [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) on that container:

```
std::vector<std::string> cols = {"A", "B", "C"};
std::vector<std::string> rows = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
std::vector<std::string> vec;
for (auto i : cols)
    for (auto j : rows)
        vec.emplace_back(i + j);
std::random_shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

And here's the [running](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a1b4757b2b7036f) code results.

---

As hinted by [DyP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp), `std::random_shuffle` might use `rand` inside its implementation (the truth is that it's implementation defined) therefore you might incur in the problem of keep getting the same results over and over again because you did not seed the random function.

Thankfully C++11 introduces `std::shuffle` that allow us to pass a third argument and define our own random generator functor. The great thing about this is that we can easily use `<random>` to feed that argument:

```
std::mt19937 rand_func(std::random_device{}());
std::shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end(), rand_func);
```

And here's the [running](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce946e2f3d3ff78f) code results.

Comment: Don't forget the seeding ;)

Comment: *"the truth that it's implementation defined"* Ah! Good catch - I didn't even bother looking it up because of the C++11 facilities ;D

Answer (score 1):

So why can't you use `rand()`? Because it *may* return a too-large value? Then pick a random value and if it's too large, (a) don't use it but pick another or (b) clip off the too large part using the `%` (modulus) operator:

```
my1stOwnRandomValue = rand() % 4;
my2ndOwnRandomValue = rand() % 4;
columnsAndRows=columns[my1stOwnRandomValue]+rows[my2ndOwnRandomValue];
```

This does not address "with no repeats", to do so you need more code. You may keep a list of 'used' values, or create a list of *all* possible combinations (after all there are only 16) and pick one at random from this list, then remove the picked combination from the list.

Comment: As an alternative to *generating* random strings you could generate the list and *shuffle* it.

Comment: Indeed, since the OP wants to avoid repeats that's preferable. I said "it needs more code" but all it needs is a *bit* of C++.

Answer (score 1):

you can use time as the seed of random function this can aviod  pseudo-random

```
srand((unsigned) time(NULL)); /*set seed must #include <time.h>*/
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
      columnValue=rand() % 4;
      rowValue=rand() % 4;
      columnsAndRows=columns[columnValue]+row[rowValue];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a C++11 version:

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

// helper to get the size (extent) of a raw array
template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t get_extent(T&)
{  return std::extent<T>::value;  }

int main()
{
    std::string const chars[] = {"A","B","C"};
    std::string const digits[] = {"1","2","3","4"};

    // vector containing the resulting strings
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    // create the "ordered" sequence A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, ..
    for(auto const& eChar : chars)
        for(auto const& eDigit : digits)
            result.push_back( eChar+eDigit );

    // shuffle the sequence
    {
        // random device to seed the PRNG
        std::random_device rd;
        // create a MT19937 PRNG, seeded
        std::mt19937 g(rd());

        std::shuffle(begin(result), end(result), g);
    }

    // output result
    for(auto const& e : result) std::cout << e << ", ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

---

A C++03 version:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

// helper to get the size (extent) of a raw array
template<class T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t get_extent(T (&)[N])
{  return N;  }

int main()
{
    std::string const chars[] = {"A","B","C"};
    std::string const digits[] = {"1","2","3","4"};

    // vector containing the resulting strings
    typedef std::vector<std::string> result_t;
    result_t result;

    // create the "ordered" sequence A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, ..
    for(std::string const* pChar = chars;
        pChar != chars + get_extent(chars);
        ++pChar)
        for(std::string const* pDigit = digits;
            pDigit != digits + get_extent(digits);
            ++pDigit)
            result.push_back( *pChar+*pDigit );

    // shuffle the sequence
    {
        std::srand( std::time(NULL) );
        std::random_shuffle(result.begin(), result.end());
    }

    // output result
    std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jongware

You can avoid generating a number larger than the provided range by using the minimum and the difference between the maximum and minimum range instead.

So rather than:

```
int x = rand() % max + min;
```

Use:

```
int diff = max - min;

int x = rand() % diff + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strcat1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
string strcat2 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int stringl1 = strcat1.size() - 1;
int stringl2 = strcat1.size() - 1;
auto strfn1 = [&]() {return strcat2[rand() % stringl2];}; //will return a single char
auto strfn2 = [&]() {return strcat2[rand() % stringl2];};
while (true)
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);

    std::string str1(1, strfn1()); //fill 1 string/char space with arg2 here strfn1
    std::string str2(1, strfn2());
    std::string str3(1, strfn2());
    str1 += str2;
    str1 = str3 + str2 + str1 + str3; //as many adjacent string as you want
    cout << str1<<" ";
}
```